# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'join'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am encountering this error on Internet Explorer 9.0 under F12 development tools, in the following statement:

```
arr = [];
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i ++) {
  console.log(items[i]);
  arr.push(items[i].join(','));
}
```

This method work on every browser except IE. Why isn't it working?

Comment: One of your "items" is not an array.

Comment: Is items[i] an array? Add a debug line in your loop.  `console.log(items[i]); arr.push(items[i].join(','));`

Comment: Since you have your developer tools open, what did you discover when you logged each item in the array you're looping?

Comment: It would help if you showed what items is also. Code snipplet does not give enough data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my guess *(since we're lacking information)*.

It could be a combination of the following:

- You're testing in IE8, or if you're using IE9, you're in Quirks Mode
- When you built the Array, you included a trailing `,`

In Quirks Mode, or in IE8 and lower, if you include a trailing comma in Array literal syntax, it'll *(incorrectly)* add an extra item the end of the Array.

This means your last item will be `undefined`, and you'll get an Error when you use `.join()`.

---

In IE8 and lower, or any version in Quirks Mode, you'll get the following:

```
var items = [
    ["foo"],
    ["bar"],
    ["baz"], // <-- trailing comma
];

alert(items.length); // 4 (should be 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by changing arr = [] to var arr = [];

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer, but would have helped me...

I thought I was using the join method as a static method of the Array type (which probably betrays my C# history) as follows:

> var s = Array.join(myArray, ",");

and unsurprisingly I can't find anyone else using that syntax.
The surprising thing is that it worked in Firefox. Didn't in IE, which is what led me here.

Changing to the more conventional

> var s = myArray.join(",");

fixed it!